# How to run a UDF on multiple rows of a pyspark dataframe in batches until the last row of the pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement of creating a new column with a UDF where it makes a FLASK-API call and gets the output in a string format.

```
def my_method(input: str):
    url = 'URL'
    payload = {}
    headers = {'Authorization': <SOME_TOKEN>}
    resp = requests.request('GET', url. headers=headers, data=payoad)
    if response.status_code=200:
        return response.text
    else:
        return response.status_code

my_udf = udf(lambda x: my_method(z), StringType())
```

My table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE student (id String, name STRING, age INT);
```

This is how I am running the UDF:

```
df = spark.sql('select * from student')
output_df = df.withColumn('api_output', my_udf(col('id')))
output_df.write.format('parquet').mode('append').saveAsTable('database.tablename')
```

I have move than 500k rows in the table.
The problem with this approach is I ran multiple times into out of memory exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : GC overhead limit exceeded
```

So is there any way I can run this UDF on a subset of rows in the table: student's ID column and loop it until the last row of the table?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula : why do you keep asking this same question on every post on pyspark stackoverflow? Are you getting paid to only help azure people?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula We do have Databricks. But not sure about the Azure specific Databricks you are asking for..

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula : but this is a general Pyspark problem, Pyspark sits on top of Databricks. Even if he answered yes, it wouldn't help you with anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're performing an expensive operation on a large dataset. UDF are not natively optimized so what you can do as first try is to adjust the memory configuration. It may be a good way to go.

Add the following JVM arg when you launch spark-shell or spark-submit if you're using YARN as a resources manager:

```
--master yarn-cluster --num-executors A --executor-cores B --executor-memory Cg --driver-memory Dg  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead= E
```

the choice of A, B, C, D & E depends on your hardware performance.

You can also persist your output dataframe before applying the udf on each row.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* create optimised approaches with native Spark Expressions using Scala but it too will only process one row at a time.

If your api call can process more than one row at a time via batching grouped records you could look to group on mods of hashes of your student id and collect_list to process more than one.  (for example mod on however many partitions you would like to process [excecutors x cores]). You can then explode the resulting list

Comment: mapPartitions is a way to process a partition if the initial setup of resources required is too much. Just do the setup once and then process the rows and output the rows. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason, you can't provide more resources, you can use following technique to process the partitions in appropriate manner. Spark is will process partitions one by one depending on how many executors you have.

```
import json
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
import requests
from pyspark.sql import Row

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


data1 = [

[1],
[2],
[3],
[4],

]
columns1 =["postId"]

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=columns1)
print("Given dataframe")
df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)

## Repartition into suitable numbers so that they get processed in proper manner.
## Increase number of parititons if still getting OOM errors.
df1 = df1.repartition(4).cache()

def my_method(input):
    # The API endpoint
    url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"
    # Adding a payload
    payload = {"id": [input], "userId": 1}
    # A get request to the API
    response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        response_json = response.json()
        return response_json
    else:
        return ""


def mapPartition_inference(partitioned_rows):

    print("Within Map partition")
    result_array_list = []
    print("For loop below")
    for row in partitioned_rows:
        result = my_method(row["postId"])
        print(result)
        result_array_list.append(Row(json.dumps(result))) ## wrap the result in the Row()
    print("result array list")
    print(result_array_list)
    return iter(result_array_list)

result_df = df1.rdd.mapPartitions(mapPartition_inference).toDF(["api_response"])


print("Result DF")
result_df.show(n=30, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
Given dataframe
+------+
|postId|
+------+
|1     |
|2     |
|3     |
|4     |
+------+

Result DF

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|api_response                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit", "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"}]|
|[{"userId": 1, "id": 3, "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut", "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"}]         |
|[{"userId": 1, "id": 2, "title": "qui est esse", "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"}]              |
|[{"userId": 1, "id": 4, "title": "eum et est occaecati", "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"}]                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```